# Find a file that is not in my WPF's exe path?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

My exe's path is `c:\dev\source\project1\bin\debug\app.exe`

but my XML file is located at `c:\dev\source\project1\file.xml`

How can I load the XML file at runtime, right now I have been hard-coding the absolute url, but I don't want to do it this way.

What happens in the scenario if I change the location or the end-user moves the file to another location, for example, `file.xml` gets moved to a sub-directory under `project1` called `sub`, would I have to change things again.  Is there way to not have to worry about were the file is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Solution Explorer go to the XML file set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer` This will put a copy of the xml file in `c:\dev\source\project1\bin\debug\` and have your program reference the version that is in the same folder as the exe.

[image]

Comment: Great this worked. Is it better to use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` or is there something better that will always be the directory of the executable?

Comment: Just to point out, I had to change the Build Action to Content.  It is Resource by default.

Comment: Yes, they may need to edit it directly at first, but later, I probably will have a GUI for it or does it matter how they edit it.

Comment: Why are you not just putting the configuration in the app.conifg file?

Comment: I never thought of that at first.

Comment: I put the data in the app.config, but it did not put the app.config in the exe directory.  Do I need to set the Build Action to Content and Copy if newer as well.  If so, what is the benefit of using the app.config as opposed to my own file?

Comment: App.conifg should automaticly be copied to the exe directory. Try using the the folder in your solution `Properties->Settings` and set your config there. that should populate app.config automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the path to your Xml file in app.config file. When the path is changed you don't have to worry about hard-coding stuff and compilation of your EXE. Simply change the path in the configuration and all good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xmlFile" value="c:\dev\source\project1\file.xml"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If the user goes haywire and decides to change directory names and file names, then wouldn't this require them to change the app.config

Comment: Yes, upon changing the file path, user can himself configure the new path of xml in the config file.